# How to transpile node_modules with Turborepo and SWC

Tags: next.js, turborepo, swc-compiler

`next-transpile-modules` works great for Next projects, but how do I transpile modules for a raw SWC build??? I stumped

Repo: https://github.com/deltaepsilon/script-kitty

I started from a Turborepo base and exported two packages, `ui` and `command-k` into a Turborepo Next app named `web`. Everything worked great once I added `ui` and `command-k` to the `next.config.js` file like so:

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['command-k', 'ui']);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
});
```

Now I've got a new app named `external` that's going to be a standalone build of the `command-k` package. This will get published to npm.

I'm using `swc-loader` to transpile it with the following config:

```js
const path = require('path');
// See https://github.com/iykekings/react-swc-loader-template

const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: 'swc-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../../packages/command-k'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../../packages/ui'),
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

I keep getting the following error when building with `yarn dev`:

```
ERROR in ../../packages/command-k/index.tsx 2:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './command-k' in '/kitty/packages/command-k'

resolve './command-k' in '/kitty/packages/command-k'
    using description file: /kitty/packages/command-k/package.json (relative path: .)
```

```js
// /packages/command-k/index.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
export { default as CommandK } from './command-k';
```

It looks like `swc-loader` is somehow unable to import from inside of a Turborepo package. It works fine if I inline the contents of `./command-k` into `/packages/command-k/index.tsx`, but `swc-loader` refuses to follow the import.

Comment: Maybe stupid click....Have you tried to change the name of command-k in something like @kytty/commandk ? (without -) . In a similar situation i had problems with package names.

Comment: I ended up solving this differently. I never tried removing the dash.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I think I switched to esbuild. I don't think I ever found a clean solution.